# South ManyToMany migration

Tags: django, django-south

I have an existing Django model that references a proxy model users.User as a ManyToMany field. I recently created an initial South migration for the model and applied it without a problem using the --fake flag.

Now, if I clone my repository anew, run syncdb, and then try to apply my migrations, I get this South error while it's processing the model with the ManyToMany field:

```
Running migrations for <app>:
 - Migrating forwards to 0001_initial.
 > <app>:0001_initial
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
... (traceback)
raise KeyError("The model '%s' from the app '%s' is not available in this migration." %    (model, app))
KeyError: "The model 'user' from the app 'users' is not available in this migration."
```

Do I need to fake the migration every time for this particular app? Anyone have experience with this error?

Answer (score 0):

Why users.User is proxy model? I think, you must use only south without syncdb in cloned repositories.

Answer (score 0):

It occurs because South (in the present version 0.8.4) can not create a correct migration for a ManyToMany relationship with a proxy model. [There is a open ticket for this issue](http://south.aeracode.org/ticket/1070). Although you can work arround it using a ManyToMany relationship with a through class.

Answer (score 0):

since it is still an open issue (in South repository as in our life of coders :)), here is my usual workarounds:

### 1. new installations

```
django-admin.py syncdb --all
django-admin.py migrate --fake
```

### 2. fix migrations (by hand)

(before)

```
    db.create_table(m2m_table_name, (
        ('id', models.AutoField(verbose_name='ID', primary_key=True, auto_created=True)),
        ('message', models.ForeignKey(orm[u'email.message'], null=False)),
        ('avcpuser', models.ForeignKey(orm[u'profiles.avcpuser'], null=False)) # this is the troublesome proxy model (profiles.avcpuser is my proxy towards auth.User
    ))
```

(after)

```
    db.create_table(m2m_table_name, (
        ('id', models.AutoField(verbose_name='ID', primary_key=True, auto_created=True)),
        ('message', models.ForeignKey(orm[u'email.message'], null=False)),
        ('avcpuser', models.ForeignKey(orm[u'auth.User'], null=False)) # replace it with a ForeignKey to the original model
    ))
```

Honestly, I'm not 100% sure this fix is "lecit" and can be listed among "best practices", but it didn't create me any problems maintaining existing and new projects, so far. To my defence, I came to this idea noticing that when South generates 1-to-many ForeignKeys for proxy models, it does it towards the original model.